# What is the difference between except and except BaseException

Tags: python, exception

What is the difference between those two:

```
except:
    # do something
```

and

```
except BaseException as be:
    print(be)
```

I mean in the first case all possible exception are caught, but is this true for the second?

Also can the error message be printed using the first case?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Practically speaking**, there is *no difference* between `except:` and `except BaseException:`, for any current Python release.

That's because you can't just raise any type of object as an exception. The [`raise` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) explicitly disallows raising anything else:

> [...] raise evaluates the first expression as the exception object. **It must be either a subclass or an instance of `BaseException`.**

Bold emphasis mine. This has not always been the case however, in older Python releases (2.4 and before) you could use *strings* as exceptions too.

The advantage then is that you get to have easy access to the caught exception. *In order to be able to add `as targetname`*, you *must* catch a specific class of exceptions, and only `BaseException` is going to do that.

You can still access the currently active exception by using [`sys.exc_info()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) though:

```
except:
    be = sys.exc_info()[1]
```

Pick what you feel is more readable for your future self and for your colleagues.

Comment: Unless you haven't put something like `BaseException = ValueError` before ;-) `except:` guarantees to always except any error.

Comment: @a_guest: yes, the *name* can still be rebound. `builtins.BaseException` is a nice fallback, but not foolproof either.

Comment: how is `except Exception` different from `except BaseException`?

Comment: @MaggieYing: `Exception` is a subclass of `BaseException`, but it is not the only such subclass. There are other subclasses too, see the [inheritance diagram in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy); those other exceptions are not really errors but signals that you *usually* would not catch.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters, the diagram is very helpful!

Answer (score 46):

**The accepted answer is <s>incorrect</s> incomplete** (at least for Python 3.6 and above).

By catching `Exception` you catch most errors - basically all the errors that any module you use might throw.

By catching `BaseException`, in addition to all the above exceptions, you also catch exceptions of the types `SystemExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt`, and `GeneratorExit`.

By catching `KeyboardInterrupt`, for example, you may stop your code from exiting after **an initiated exit by the user** (like pressing `^C` in the console, or stopping launched application on some interpreters). This could be a wanted behavior (for example - to log an exit), but **should be used with extreme care!**

In the above example, by catching `BaseException`, you may cause your application to hang when you want it to exit.

Comment: The accepted answer is perfectly *correct*. However, it is *incomplete* without the caveat noted in this answer, so thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @itsadok You're right. I altered my answer.